# sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InternalError_) failed to find conversion function from unknown to description_enum

Tags: sqlalchemy

Using SQL, I get what I want with a `UNION` of two queries, where the first subquery returns a value from an aliased enum column and the second subquery returns `NULL` for that aliased column.

```sql
SELECT table.enumcol AS description
FROM table
WHERE <expression1>

UNION

SELECT NULL AS description
FROM t
WHERE <expression_2>
;
```

With SQLAlchemy, I can get close but not quite all the way.

```py
q1 = (
    self.dbsession.query(
        Table.enumcol.label("description")
    )
    .filter(<expression_1>)
    .subquery()
)

q2 = (
    self.dbsession.query(
        literal(None).label("description")
    )
    .filter(<expression_2>)
    .subquery()
)

union_list = (
    self.dbsession.query("description")
    .select_entity_from(
        union_all(q1.select(), q2.select())
    )
    .all()
)
```

Here's the error message:

`sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InternalError_) failed to find conversion function from unknown to description_enum`

I have no clue what to try to resolve this.

For the record, I originally wrote each subquery separately, first in SQL, then in SQLAlchemy using `.all()` instead of `.subquery()` and `union_all()`. I was able to run each one successfully, returning correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user jjhoo in [#sqlalchemy in IRC](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=sqlalchemy), they gave me the hint to not use `.subquery()` and use `.union_all()` more effectively. Here's the solution that works for me.

```py
q1 = (
    self.dbsession.query(
        Table.enumcol.label("description")
    )
    .filter(<expression_1>)
)

q2 = (
    self.dbsession.query(
        literal(None).label("description")
    )
    .filter(<expression_2>)
)

union_list = q1.union_all(q2).all()
```